# Changing android autocompletetextview underline colour, when input is in correct?

Tags: android, styles, autocompletetextview

I have a spinner with a list of items, adapted to an autocomplete textView the user needs to start typing and if the text inserted isn't contained within list, i need the underline to change color, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```